# Run-time error '13' "Type Mismatch" on If Then Statement

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm getting a run-time error '13' (type mismatch) for the following code and I can't figure out why.  It was working before I added the "and" and the second condition.  The first (a, 43) value is an error reading as "#N/A".
Any ideas?

```
If IsNumeric(Sheets("Reuters").Cells(a, 43).Value) = True And _ 
Abs(Sheets("Reuters").Cells(a, 43).Value) >= 0.0799 Then
        pfl = "P"
        ct = ct + 1
    Else
        pfl = Empty
    End If
```

Comment: Whats the value of the cell Sheets("Reuters").Cells(a, 43).Value.  Try casting to the data type double or integer before passing to the Abs function.

Comment: `And` in VBA doesn't "short circuit"  - even if the first expression evaluates to False, the second expression will still be evaluated.  So even if your `IsNumeric()` reports `False`, it will still try to run the `Abs()` part.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for posting that, I didn't know that and it will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to say

```
pfl = Empty
If IsNumeric(Sheets("Reuters").Cells(a, 43).Value) Then
    If Abs(Sheets("Reuters").Cells(a, 43).Value) >= 0.0799 Then
        pfl = "P"
        ct = ct + 1
    End If
End If
```